# Creating new user with validated data

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use a clean syntax I use in my update functions, but I am having problems.

I created a form to create an Admin (type of user).  The form passes to the Store function of my controller, validates, and should create an Admin and update that Admin with the info submitted.

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate ([
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => '',
        'phone_number' => '',
        'password' => '',

    ]);

    $internalAdmin = new Admin;
    $internalAdmin->update($data);
    $internalAdmin->save();
}
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `admins` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-12-18 16:10:00, 2019-12-18 16:10:00))

Comment: make sure the `email` passed in request because it shouldn't be null

Comment: Along with what @Joseph said, make sure 'email' is in the $fillable array on the user model `->update()` is a mass assignment method so the properties you pass to it have to be fillalbe to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark here but calling `->update()` on a model that hasn't been saved to the database yet doesn't make any sense, try the following and see if it passes for you

```
$internalAdmin = Admin::create($data);
```

The difference between `new Admin` and create is just that the new creates a new object, but it only exists in memory at that point, where `Admin::create()` creates the object, fills in the fields with whats been passed to it, and saves the record to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provide email default as not null

That’s why you show error

If you try email as default null or go to database as mark on default null

You will not showed this error again.

Comment: I added required to the validation.  I also made sure I had an email address filled in the form.  Still the same error

Comment: I think this has to do with me having a guard in the Admin model.  I have two login systems (users and admins).  I have this is the Admin model:      protected $guard = 'admin';.  I didn't think this would impact creating a new Admin in my code above